# NSDateFormatter iOS, date pattern

Tags: ios, date, formatter

I just simply can't figure out how to set NSDateFormatter date format so [formatter dateWithString:] does not return a nil.

The date looks as follows :

> 2008-08-18T14:32:22.1875000+01:00

I tried

```
formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzz+GMT"];
```

Doesn't seem to work :(. Any suggestions, please help.

Ok thanks for answering, it seems like I mislead people with my question a little so I try to rephrase it, sorry for that, maybe its just bit late for programming. I need a date wrapper object so I don't have to parse the string containing the date myself. Basically I get a string from a Database I need to parse to I can use it in my UI.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZ";
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2008-08-18T14:32:22.1875000+01:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

That prints nil

What I want is NSString->NSDat, so I can ask it maybe what month it contains, or what time it contains. I see now that NSDate does not have such method. That was a foolish thing to assume. Any Ideas,now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [unicode documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) there's no *f*. Assuming you want subseconds, that should be *S*. You also need to put the *T* in quotes if you want it to transfer literally. I think you're confused about *z* too, and probably want *ZZZZ* rather than *zz+GMT*. So:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZ";
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Per the [QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html), you may also want explicitly to set a locale of `en_US_POSIX`, if you want to produce a technical string for storage. It reserves the right to adjust your requested fields otherwise per the current locale, assuming you want to display the string. So that'd be:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
formatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZ";
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

As per ctrahey's answer, that doesn't quite get the format you want, ending up at e.g.

```
012-06-22T16:44:32.9310000GMT-07:00
```

i.e. the letters 'GMT' have crept in there. Switching to a single Z gets rid of the explicit reference to GMT but also removes the colon.

Edit: per your example code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZZZZ";
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2008-08-18T14:32:22.1875000+01:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

That fails because your input string doesn't match the supplied date format — it's missing the letters GMT before the +01:00. Since there doesn't seem to be a unicode date string that exactly matches what you have in your database, probably the easiest thing is just to remove the colons. E.g.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSSSZ";
formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSString *sourceString = @"2008-08-18T14:32:22.1875000+01:00";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[sourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

For me that outputs `2008-08-18 13:32:22 +0000`.

Comment: I updated the question so maybe you can help me now too :D Also why are you autoreleasing the objects?I am using ARC so I dont need to do that, right?

Comment: @foFox, correct.  you don't need to (and actually **can't**) use `autorelease` in ARC code.  but, some people still need to use non-ARC code, for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could get only leaves out the colon in the zone offset near the end:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"];
```

Which looks like this: 2012-06-22T16:40:46.6290000-0700

The documentation I was using [is here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), as linked [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)